# javascript How to make div id="odometerDiv" change its width on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, media-queries, window-resize

How to make div id="odometerDiv" change its width on window resize so that:

1. above 600px width there is larger width breakpoint and
2. below 600px there is smaller width breakpoint?

Below is my attepmt:

https://jsfiddle.net/xawyvwm4/2/

line 4 in jsFiddle:

```
if($(document).width() > 600) {
  this.digits = 6;
  this.tenths = 0;
  this.digitHeight = 27;
  this.digitPadding = 5;
  this.digitWidth = 20;
  this.bustedness = 2;
  this.fontStyle = "font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace; font-weight: 900;";
  this.value = -1;
    } else {
  this.digits = 6;
  this.tenths = 0;
  this.digitHeight = 17;
  this.digitPadding = 5;
  this.digitWidth = 10;
  this.bustedness = 2;
  this.fontStyle = "font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace; font-weight: 900;";
  this.value = -1;  
  }
```

Line 139 in jsFiddle:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  odometer();
});
```

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why would you not use CSS for this?

Comment: I've tried CSS and after applying css div id="odometerDiv" stops

Comment: I don't see any `div` with that `id` **in the question**.

Comment: your code has an error `odometer is not a function` check the console in your jsfiddle

Comment: Probably because of jsFiddle's stupid^H^H^H^H^H^H *surprising* default of wrapping all your code in an `onload` callback. So, again, Stack Snippets (or at least all code here on-site) would help.